# XCode Code Signing: Communication with Apple failed

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

On one of my build machines it has a persistent bad request (400) error communicating with Apple when it tries to download a certificate for automatic code signing. I've actually put the certificates on the machine manually so it shouldn't need to download a certificate.

This happens with two different Apple accounts on multiple projects, while other build machines have no issues. Interestingly changing to the personal team of one of the accounts works and it then complains that the bundle ID is already in use (as expected).

Note that I've redacted the team name and bundle IDs, it's not that they're missing!

I've looked around at other reports of 'communication with apple failed' but they're either unanswered or due to different errors/situations.

If it's relevant this is XCode 9.3 on High Sierra

[image: error image]

Comment: It's selected, just redacted, before uploading it was showing as grey box so was clearer!

Comment: No that's all fine, from the same machine also.

Comment: Try this also: Xcode (Menu) >> Preferences >> Accounts >> Download Manual Profiles

Comment: Downloading manual profiles appears to work, get an activity indicator that fills up and no errors reported (though knowing apple that doesn't mean it worked).

Not sure how to reset the network connection, a guide suggested deleting Library/Preferences/SystemConifguration but it won't let me do that as it's 'required by macOS'

Comment: Remove tick mark - **Automatically manage signing**